# create count up timer with typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timer, frontend

I have a problem with setInterval() in my angular project

this is my code

```
    recordingTimer: any = '00:00:00';
  timer: boolean = true;
  recording(){
    ////// please type recording meeting functionality here
    if (this.timer) {
      let seconds = 0;
      let minutes = 0;
      let hours = 0;

      seconds += 1;

      if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes += 1

        if (minutes >= 60) {
          minutes = 0;
          hours += 1
        }
      }

      /// update recording time
      this.recordingTimer = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
      console.log(this.recordingTimer)

    }


  }

  repeat() {
    setInterval(() => this.recording(), 1000);
  }
```

why the console.log statement repeated but with the same value "00:00:01"

please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the variable hour second minute are local to the function and will be zero on each call. So try this

```
//class variables

       seconds = 0;
       minutes = 0;
       hours = 0;

recording(){
    ////// please type recording meeting functionality here
    if (this.timer) {

      this.seconds += 1;

      if (this.seconds >= 60) {
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.minutes += 1

        if (this.minutes >= 60) {
          this.minutes = 0;
          this.hours += 1
        }
      }

      console.log(this.hours, this.minutes, this.seconds);

      /// update recording time
      this.recordingTimer = (this.hours ? (this.hours > 9 ? this.hours : "0" + this.hours) : "00") + ":" + (this.minutes ? (this.minutes > 9 ? this.minutes : "0" + this.minutes) : "00") + ":" + (this.seconds > 9 ? this.seconds : "0" + this.seconds);
      console.log(this.recordingTimer)

    }
```

Also dont forget to clear these variable when you clear the timer

Answer (score 1):

A simple timer example is here:

```
export class AppComponent {
  startTime: Date;
  stopTime: Date;
  active: boolean = false
  get display() { return (this.startTime && this.stopTime) ? +this.stopTime - +this.startTime : 0 }

  timer() {
    if (this.active) {
      this.stopTime = new Date()
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.timer()
      }, 1000)
    }
  }

  start() {
    this.startTime = new Date()
    this.stopTime = this.stopTime
    this.active = true
    this.timer()
  }

  stop() {
    this.stopTime = new Date()
    this.active = false
  }
}
```

You can see it in action at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jezrv3

**EDIT**

A simple timer with pause and resume as requested at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nds8jp

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can I pause timer in this way?

Comment: Ok. Adding a pause option to it.

Comment: it will be very kind of you